# MySQL - INSERT or JOIN Table rows for every ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have a table for ordered items. What I want to happen is, for every ordered items, an extra row is inserted just right below them.

Note: Every sales order can have 1 or more ordered items.

This is the table for the ordered items:

[image]

This is the table result that I want to be achieved:

[image]

Please let me know. What is the proper MySQL query to achieve this. Thanks for any help

Comment: Use a `before trigger` probably.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the quick reply. Do you have a basic query to start for this situation?

Comment: I think best would be, managing this from your application end rather in DB end cause, in desired screen when order_id = 16, you want to insert only one row for shipment. How will you know that the next insert order_id is same as previous one? So, try managing it from app code and then fire the insert accordingly.

Comment: Hi Rahul, that database design is based from woocommerce plugin for wordpress. a certain sales order id = 16 can have multiple items. that is how woocommerce structures their db. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a trigger or write a SQL transaction comprising of 2 row inserted in the table.

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 
//INSERT QUERY FOR ITEM 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$type."', ".$order_id.")");
//INSERT QUERY FOR FREE SHIPPING 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id) VALUES ('Free Shipping', 'shipping', ".$order_id.")");
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the idea. Do you think that the second screenshot is possible to be implemented?

Comment: Yes, of course.

`SET AUTOCOMMIT=0
//INSERT QUERY FOR ITEM
//INSERT QUERY FOR FREE SHIPPING
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1`

Comment: I see. I will try what you said. I really have not thought of a basic way to do this. Hmmm.. Do you have a code snippet to how can i basically do this Sir?

Comment: I assume order_item_id to be autoincrement and order_id as Integer

`SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$type."', ".$order_id.")");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id) VALUES ('Free Shipping', 'shipping', ".$order_id.")");

SET AUTOCOMMIT=1`